# Found vs Find Correct sentence

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

**1.**

> What would you do if we found life on Mars?

OR

> What would you do if we find life on Mars?

---

**2.**

> He hasn't still find out the secret

OR

> He hasn't still found out the secret

Please give some explanation with answers.

Comment: 1. is correct. 2. What would you do if we found life on Mars? or What will you do if we find life on Mars? [see "Usage of “would” and “will”"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/usage-of-would-and-will); 3. He hasn't found out the secret (yet), (present perfect is have/+past participle). For still and yet see [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/935/understanding-still-and-yet-usage).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is homework and we do not do your homework for you

Comment: Neither of the sentences regarding the secret are correct. "Still" should precede "hasn't", not follow it.

Comment: Though it's like a homework but it is helpful for people who is self taught learner and want to get answer from stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3):

1 - I have one rule for you: keep the tenses consistent.

*Would* is the past tense of *will.*  This does not mean that it is always used in the past tense, however.  The past tense is often used in English to denote a distant possibility for the present or future; it is essentially a makeshift subjunctive mood.  Thus,

> 'What *will* you do if we *find* life on mars?'

represents a possibility that the speaker believes really may happen; however,

> 'What *would* you do if we *found* life on mars?'

represents a possibility that is unlikely or far-fetched.  In conversation, few people will mark the distinction, however, and the most important factor is to ensure that *will* be matched with *find* and *would* with *found*--essentially present with present and past with past.

2 -  The present perfect always uses a participle after the verb *to have,* never an infinitive.

The principle parts of the verb *to find* are *find, found, found,* the first of which is the bare infinitive, the second the preterite (past tense), and the third the past participle.

Though with the verb *to find* the difference between preterite and past participle is unclear, it is quite obvious in verbs like *to eat* (*eat, ate, eaten*).  Additionally, *still* usually goes before the main verb.

The important thing to remember is that the present perfect always uses *to have* and the past participle.  Thus,

> He still *hasn't found* out the secret.

is the only possibility.